# version is incompatible with this server version. How to upgrade?

Tags: sql-server, database, restore

I am getting below error in Upgrade. Please help in how to upgrade in this scenario.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The database was backed up on a server
>   running version 14.00.2002. That version is incompatible with this
>   server, which is running version 13.00.2216. Either restore the
>   database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is
>   compatible with this server. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot restore SQL Server backups on lower versions.  In your case, you are backing up on SQL Server 2017, and trying to restore on SQL Server 2016.  This is not allowed.  If you backup on SQL Server 2017, you can only restore on SQL Server 2017 or higher version.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are trying to restore to older version(SQL Server 2016) from newer version backup(SQL Server 2017). This is not supported.

The way to get the database to older version is:

1. **Schema movement**: Get the database DDL creation scripts from newer version and create a fresh database in older version. If you have some new feature, which is not supported in older version, then you have to think of workaround.
2. **Data movement**: Data Import wizard or SSIS or some other ETL approach to move data from newer version to older version.

Now, you have got both Schema and data available in the older version.